# Bootstrap Modal popup not scrolling with keyboard

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap modal, I added a scroll bar and it works fine with the mouse, but when I use the keyboard only the background page scrolls. What can I do to solve this. This is the css code that I'm using.

```
.modal .modal-body {
height: 520px;
overflow-y: auto;
 }
```

I tried this code but it doesn't work

```
  $('#myModal').keydown(function(e) 
{ 
    if(e.keyCode == 40){$('.modal-body').scrollTop($('.modal-body').scrollTop()+10);}
    if(e.keyCode == 38){$('.modal-body').scrollTop($('.modal-body').scrollTop()-10);}

});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Keystrokes are only detected by the element that currently has the focus, so your `keydown` event won't trap anything if the focus is on an element in the background. I suggest doing the following:

- Making your modal focusable by giving it the `tabIndex=-1` attribute
- Setting it to have the focus when it opens, like this: 
   $("#my-modal").focus()

Comment: Thanks man!! Works like a charm. I'm not good enough to vote up :)